# Installing tekton encountered forbidden message

Tags: openshift, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I am trying to install Tekton. But upon trying to install the dashboard I have encountered an error "forbidden".  I would like to install task, pipeline, and triggers

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to further elaborate. What is your issue exactly: what did you do, what are you trying to do, what error are you seeing, when, ... Current question is just too vague to answer, we have no idea what's your situation.

Comment: "Error loading Pipelines Forbidden" I am receiving this error in tekton dashboard

Comment: Please edit your initial post. And while I can now guess what's your issue, I'ld argue we still don't have any context, no idea what you did to get here ... So here you go, you get a context-less answer: the container running your dashboard does not have privileges querying your kubernetes API. Not knowing which flavor of tekton you installed, nor which flavor of kubernetes you run ... you'ld have to figure this out.

Comment: I think the issue is that no cluster has been present when I tried to execute the command: 
 tkn clustertasks ls

Comment: You make no sense (keep in mind, while we don't know much from your initial question: it does mention your issue involves dashboards). Now you're talking about tkn cli. Would you, once and for all, edit your original post, and explain to us what is your situation? You won't get any help, from putting random words one after another.

Comment: Here are the steps which I performed:

Comment: I have installed tekton In Openshift cluster platform and I am trying to create a simple pipeline. But when I am trying to install it I encounter an issue "no clustertask found". I also installed openshift pipeline operators in Openshift but got no luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask